# Position button over image Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to position my button centrally vertically and horizontal over my image.

How do I do this with the code? **Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/bdec5ezo/

Also, once it gets to tablet and mobile, can I push me button so it's on the left hand side and not centered?

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%
}

.btn {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 1px solid #ffca00;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffca00;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 55px;
    text-shadow: none;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

.row {
  position:relative
}

button {
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:40%
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=141&txt=2073%C3%97563&w=2073&h=563">
          <a href="http://www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-default btn-yellow" type="submit">Shop Now</button></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/arifahmedjoy/bdec5ezo/2/)

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

img {
  max-width:100%
}

.btn {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 1px solid #ffca00;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffca00;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 55px;
    text-shadow: none;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.row {
  position:relative
}

button {
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:38%
  
}
@media (max-width:768px){
  button {left:0%}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=141&txt=2073%C3%97563&w=2073&h=563">
          <a href="http://www.google.com"><button class="btn btn-default btn-yellow" type="submit">Shop Now</button></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the right idea but the button is the wrong way around. Is it easy to make it horizontal again. Sorry, it's my poor explanation here.

Comment: Yes, just remove these three lines `-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(90deg);`

Comment: Updated here: https://jsfiddle.net/bdec5ezo/4/ You're a star, Arif - thank you very very much :-)

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 1):

remove padding in .btn class then you can see your button centre respect to height and width

To have it responsive in mobile and tablet you have to use media query

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the padding and set the width/height on `.btn`. How do I center it horizontally & vertically? https://jsfiddle.net/bdec5ezo/3/

Comment: @media{
    button{
    remove left:40%;
}
}

Answer (score 1):

There are already great answers , but I have another version here , 
my approach promise accurate vertical align in any kind of device~
but have revised a little more your original code , 
maybe you can have a look =)
https://jsfiddle.net/Carr1005/qkzstpvv/1/

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.btn {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 1px solid #ffca00;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #ffca00;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 55px;
    text-shadow: none;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

.row {
  position:relative;
  background-image:url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=141&txt=2073%C3%97563&w=2073&h=563");
  background-size:     cover;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height:150px;  /*need to adjust*/
}

a {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  text-decoration:none;
}
```